# Video cannot be uploaded to server side [react native + codeigniter]

Tags: codeigniter, react-native, file-upload, codeigniter-restserver

I faced this problem since yesterday and I am still unable to find a solution for this. I just don't have any idea why was the video cannot be uploaded by using rest server.

I am using **react native document picker** with **axios** to upload files to server side and it's working fine with image but not video. It always return the error

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

**From my react native - to submit files :**

```
_submitPost(){
  const configuration = {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  }

  const data = new FormData();
  if(this.state.fileUri != null){
    data.append('files', {
      uri: this.state.fileUri,
      type: this.state.fileType,
      name: this.state.fileName
    });
  }

  axios.post("api-url-goes-here", data, configuration).then(res=>{
    if(res.data.status == true){
        console.log('uploaded')
    } else {
        console.log('failed to upload')
    }
  })
}
```

The file type is `video/mp4` and the file name is `video_20190424_125833.mp4`

**From CodeIgniter server side**

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['name'])){
    $postAttc = $this->upload_files(POSTS_DIR, 'files', 'mp4|3gp|jpg|jpeg|png|gif');
} else {
    $postAttc = null;
}

$this->response([
    'http_status_code' => REST_Controller::HTTP_OK,
    'status' => true,
    'postAttc' => $postAttc,
    'statusMsg' => 'OK'
], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

**And here is my upload_files() function to upload the file**

```
public function upload_files($upload_path, $fileName, $file_types){
    $config['upload_path']          = $upload_path;
    $config['allowed_types']        = $file_types;
    $config['max_size']             = 0;

    $config['file_name'] = uniqid();

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload($fileName)){
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $uploadData['file_name'];

        return $file_name;
    } else {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code because I've tried applying exactly the same code for web version to upload video and it was a success but not with uploading from react native.

Comment: well i would go ahead and first check to see what the file mime is using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php and see if that mime exists in config/mime.php. usually you see this kind of error when the mime doesn't exist in the database, or if it does, the file might not match the exact definition in mime.php

Comment: I changed the `$config['allowed_types'] = '*'` and it works fine now.

Comment: yup, and it also allows `.exe` .. yikes! mimes are there for your servers protection! if you or a good admin is the only one uploading files I wouldn't worry about it, otherwise, no bueno!

Comment: Yes but I wrote my own file extension filtration before it firing up the file upload function. So it should be fine.

Comment: ok, just to make sure though, you aren't using purely the `.jpg` extension to filter, right? i can easily change a nefarious script to be any extension i want, that is what mime filtration is for, because it is more difficult for a file to hide it's contents.